# Good Angular Tutorials for Consuming Rest API's

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Have we got some good, easy to use tutorials for working with API's?  Im writing a UI for an API im developing and want to really learn how to use AngularJS properly.

thanks

Comment: Flagging as off topic, this is not a programming question as per:

Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, the `$resource` service is designed specially for consuming REST services.  You can find the documentation (and a few samples) for `$resource` at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource.